# extracting large layer netcdf using r

Tags: r, netcdf

i am trying to extract layers from a large netcdf file using r
my nc file variable are

```
 5 variables:"
 [1] "        double time_bnds[bnds,time] "
 [1] "        double plev_bnds[bnds,plev] "
 [1] "        double lat_bnds[bnds,lat] "
 [1] "        double lon_bnds[bnds,lon] "
 [1] "        float hur[lon,lat,plev,time] "
 [1] "            standard_name: relative_humidity"
 [1] "            long_name: Relative Humidity"
```

so i want to get the relative humidity (hur) data for all the lon and lat for a specific plev and specific time

```
plev<-get.var.ncdf(ncin,"plev")
time<-get.var.ncdf(ncin,"time")
plev2<-plev[2]
time2<-time[2]
hur<-get.var.ncdf(ncin,"hur",start=c(1,1,plev2,time2), count=c(1,1,2,2))
```

i am getting this error

```
Error in R_nc_get_vara_double: NetCDF: Index exceeds dimension bound
Var: hur  Ndims: 4   Start: 711901,92499,0,0Count: 2,2,144,192Error in                  


get.var.ncdf(ncin, "hur", start = c(1, 1, plev2, time2), count = c(-1,  : 
 C function R_nc_get_vara_double returned error
```

how do i solve this

edit------

solution

lat and lon is a vector

```
 hur<-get.var.ncdf(ncin,"hur", start=c(1,1,2,2),count=c(dim(lon),dim(lat),1,1))

previously i kept directly the values of plev2 but we shud mention the index which is 2
```

thank you @pascal

Comment: If you want a specific level and time, and all longitudes and latitudes, `count` should be something like `c(144, 73, 1, 1)`.

Comment: hur<-get.var.ncdf(ncin,"hur", start=c(lon[1],lat[1],plev2,time2), count=c(dim(lon),dim(lat),1,1))     getting the same error !

Comment: If `lon` and `lat` are vectors, don't use `dim`. If they are matrices, you need the number of rows and columns.

Comment: thank you it worked i have edited what i did